# Android app to track time a child spends on a tablet?

Tags: android, timer

Is there some kind of background process or app that a parent could install on a tablet to track the time his/her child spends on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Digital Wellbeing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.wellbeing&hl=en_US) on my phone to keep track of time spent on apps, and also set the time limit on each app. I have the latest Android OS, so not sure if it will work with your tablet.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I installed it on my android phone and it works well, I'll try on the tablet now